# Closure/Interior Operator Definition

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand the (Kuratowski) closure operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms). The idea is pretty clear to me however I got stuck in the proofs and maybe this is due to a wrong/unclear definition of the terms I am using:

I defined a topology by a subset $\mathcal T$ of the powerset $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ which includes $\emptyset$, $\Omega$ and is stable under finite intersection/arbitrary unions. Moreover, the interior/closure operator are defined by 
$$\mathsf{interior}(V) = \bigcup\Big\{X\in\mathcal T : X\subseteq V\Big\}\\\mathsf{closure}(V) = \bigcap\Big\{\complement X\in\mathcal T : V\subseteq X\Big\}$$
for $V\in$ the powerset. Note that I do not use the terms "open" or "closed" set which is why I have to use $\complement X\in\mathcal T$ to indicate $X$ is closed.

Are these definitions correct? I usually encounter the terms with the terms "open" or "closed set" (e.g. the interior of $V$ is then defined as "the largest open subset of $V$) but as I said these terms are not available for me.

Comment: The second one is not correct. Note that you intersect open sets there.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks. I if I changed it to $\bigcap\{\complement X : X\in\mathcal T, V\subseteq X\}$, would it then be correct?

Comment: Nope.Think about it.

Comment: Only an intersection of subsets that all contain $V$ will contain $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure of $V$ is the intersection of all closed subsets of $X$ that contain $V$ as a subset. And a closed set in $X$ is one whose complement
relative to $X$ is in the topology $\mathcal{T}$.

So $$\operatorname{cl}(V) = \bigcap \{A \subseteq X: (X\setminus A \in \mathcal{T}) \land (V \subseteq A)\}$$

In the OP's definition of closure he's intersecting the complement of $X$? which is empty, as $X$ is the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of interior is correct.

Your definition of closure is not because even if $X \in {\cal T}$ (i.e., $X$ is open), its complement $\complement X$ need not be in ${\cal T}$ (i.e., not every closed set is open).  But that's what would need to be the case if your current definition of closure (i.e., closure$(V)= \bigcap \{\complement X \in {\cal T}: V \subseteq X \}$) were correct.

You can fix the definition as follows: closure$(V)= \bigcap \{X \in {\cal P}(\Omega): \complement X \in {\cal T} \mbox{ and }  V \subseteq X \}$.  That equation says the closure of $V$ is the intersection of all closed sets (i.e., complements of open sets) that contain $V$.

Comment: You're using $X$ twice in different meanings? Better use another free variable..

Comment: Or you need to use $\Omega$, as the OP does: so $X \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ instead.